If QFT is relativistic approach of QM, how does the concept of probability distribution of location of a particle evolve along the way?
When I first found out that QFT says if the value of the field associated with some particle is high at some point in space it means a particle will be localized there, more specifically, will be created at that point in space. Then I thought okay QFT allows for particles to be created, then maybe for already existing particles a high value of the field might mean higher probability of finding the particles there; just as a similar concept we learn in quantum mechanics. But I later found out it is not that straightforward.
QFT describes a particle as excitement of its field, and motion of that excitement is movement of the particle. This neatly combines the wave particle dual nature of a particle, as pointed out by many in their comments on the internet. But if probability distribution of location is not a concept in QFT, since it is in QM and QM is non-relativistic limit of QFT, then from what concept in QFT do we get down to it in QM in non-relativistic limit?

For a connection between Schr. eq. and Klein-Gordon eq, see e.g. A. Zee, QFT in a Nutshell, Sec. III.5, and this Phys.SE post plus links therein.
